# How to write properly Json using RestFul Web Services with bi-directional Entities?

Tags: mysql, json, hibernate, rest, jersey

I am having a small problem trying to get a Json result, I have 2 tables (route and destination) with the following structure:

route:
[route table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr8uf.png)

And destination:
[destination table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH8Qz.png)

Route.class

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Route {
private int idroute;
private String routename;
private Double price;
private String description;
private String city;
private Collection<Destination> destinationsByIdroute;

@Id
@Column(name = "idroute", nullable = false)
public int getIdroute() {
    return idroute;
}

public void setIdroute(int idroute) {
    this.idroute = idroute;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "routename", nullable = true, length = 45)
public String getRoutename() {
    return routename;
}

public void setRoutename(String routename) {
    this.routename = routename;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "price", nullable = true, precision = 2)
public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 500)
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "city", nullable = true, length = 30)
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Route route = (Route) o;

    if (idroute != route.idroute) return false;
    if (routename != null ? !routename.equals(route.routename) : route.routename != null) return false;
    if (price != null ? !price.equals(route.price) : route.price != null) return false;
    if (description != null ? !description.equals(route.description) : route.description != null) return false;
    if (city != null ? !city.equals(route.city) : route.city != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = idroute;
    result = 31 * result + (routename != null ? routename.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (price != null ? price.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (city != null ? city.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "routeByIdroute")
public Collection<Destination> getDestinationsByIdroute() {
    return destinationsByIdroute;
}

public void setDestinationsByIdroute(Collection<Destination>       destinationsByIdroute) {
    this.destinationsByIdroute = destinationsByIdroute;
}
}
```

Destinatio Class:

```
@Entity
public class Destination {
private int iddestination;
private String frompoint;
private String topoint;
private Route routeByIdroute;

@Id
@Column(name = "iddestination", nullable = false)
public int getIddestination() {
    return iddestination;
}

public void setIddestination(int iddestination) {
    this.iddestination = iddestination;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "frompoint", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getFrompoint() {
    return frompoint;
}

public void setFrompoint(String frompoint) {
    this.frompoint = frompoint;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "topoint", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getTopoint() {
    return topoint;
}

public void setTopoint(String topoint) {
    this.topoint = topoint;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Destination that = (Destination) o;

    if (iddestination != that.iddestination) return false;
    if (frompoint != null ? !frompoint.equals(that.frompoint) : that.frompoint != null) return false;
    if (topoint != null ? !topoint.equals(that.topoint) : that.topoint != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = iddestination;
    result = 31 * result + (frompoint != null ? frompoint.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (topoint != null ? topoint.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idroute", referencedColumnName = "idroute")
public Route getRouteByIdroute() {
    return routeByIdroute;
}

public void setRouteByIdroute(Route routeByIdroute) {
    this.routeByIdroute = routeByIdroute;
}
```

}

RouteService.class

```
public class RouteService extends HibernateUtils {
public static List<Route> getAllRoutes() {

    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
    try {
        System.out.println("querying all the managed entities...");
        session.beginTransaction();
        routes = session.createQuery("select r from Route r join fetch r.destinationsByIdroute d", Route.class).list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(HibernateException hbe){
        hbe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return routes;
}
```

}

And MyResource.class

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Route> getRoutes() {

    List<Route> route = null;
    try{
        route = RouteService.getAllRoutes();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return route;
}
```

}

this code works but i dont know why is giving me 3 results if i only have just 1 record in my route table:

```
[
{
"city": "Santo Domingo",
"description": "los coquitos, farmacia enriquillo",
"destinationsByIdroute": [
  {
    "frompoint": "18.479081, -69.978025",
    "iddestination": 3,
    "topoint": "18.477886, -69.968940"
  },
  {
    "frompoint": "18.470278, -69.994422",
    "iddestination": 1,
    "topoint": "18.473354, -69.993565"
  },
  {
    "frompoint": "18.473354, -69.993565",
    "iddestination": 2,
    "topoint": "18.479081, -69.978025"
  }
],
"idroute": 1,
"price": 30,
"routename": "Las caobas-Kilometro 9"
```

},
  {
    "city": "Santo Domingo",
    "description": "los coquitos, farmacia enriquillo",
    "destinationsByIdroute": [
      {
        "frompoint": "18.479081, -69.978025",
        "iddestination": 3,
        "topoint": "18.477886, -69.968940"
      },
      {
        "frompoint": "18.470278, -69.994422",
        "iddestination": 1,
        "topoint": "18.473354, -69.993565"
      },
      {
        "frompoint": "18.473354, -69.993565",
        "iddestination": 2,
        "topoint": "18.479081, -69.978025"
      }
    ],
    "idroute": 1,
    "price": 30,
    "routename": "Las caobas-Kilometro 9"
  },
  {
    "city": "Santo Domingo",
    "description": "los coquitos, farmacia enriquillo",
    "destinationsByIdroute": [
      {
        "frompoint": "18.479081, -69.978025",
        "iddestination": 3,
        "topoint": "18.477886, -69.968940"
      },
      {
        "frompoint": "18.470278, -69.994422",
        "iddestination": 1,
        "topoint": "18.473354, -69.993565"
      },
      {
        "frompoint": "18.473354, -69.993565",
        "iddestination": 2,
        "topoint": "18.479081, -69.978025"
      }
    ],
    "idroute": 1,
    "price": 30,
    "routename": "Las caobas-Kilometro 9"
  }
]

And i want something like this:

```
{
"city": "Santo Domingo",
"description": "los coquitos, farmacia enriquillo",
"destinationsByIdroute": [
  {
    "frompoint": "18.479081, -69.978025",
    "iddestination": 3,
    "topoint": "18.477886, -69.968940"
  },
  {
    "frompoint": "18.470278, -69.994422",
    "iddestination": 1,
    "topoint": "18.473354, -69.993565"
  },
  {
    "frompoint": "18.473354, -69.993565",
    "iddestination": 2,
    "topoint": "18.479081, -69.978025"
  }
],
"idroute": 1,
"price": 30,
"routename": "Las caobas-Kilometro 9"
```

}

if you see is the same result but just one time which is what i want, not 3 times like the first example.

Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can i assume you have 3 records in your destination table because you do not have any criteria filtering that join at all. routes = session.createQuery("select r from Route r join fetch r.destinationsByIdroute d", Route.class).list();

Comment: @Chris Thompson, yes my destination table has 3 records, i'm not sure how to  write the hql systax to get what i want, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you'd be able to do something like:

```
session.createQuery("select r from Route r join fetch r.destinationsByIdroute d WHERE r.idroute = d.idroute", Route.class);
```

But you are going to eventually want to probably pass in a route into this method and filter route with a parameter.
But i think this will filter your destination results to just one record.